# Pass openGL parameter to AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, variadic-functions, primitive

How do I correctly pass the javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10 to AsyncTask as a parameter. Here is the code that I tried but didn't work. If I pass the parameter to SavePNG method directly it worked. Any clue? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
if (mTakeScreenshot) {
    mTakeScreenshot = false;
    MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(0, 0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight, gl);
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute(params);
}

private static class MyTaskParams {
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
    GL10 gl;

    MyTaskParams(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.gl = gl;
    }
}

public class MyTask  extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
        int x = params[0].x;
        int y = params[0].y;
        int w = params[0].w;
        int h = params[0].h;
        GL10 gl = params[0].gl;

        SavePNG(0, 0, w,  h,  gl);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL framebuffer operations are single-threaded,
so you will need to use a callback function and call it when necessary,
usually in a key or button press callback function.

i.e.

```
void main()
{
   //GL Operations

   //GLswapbuffers

   //call here or in key / button press callback function
   doInBackground(params);
}

 protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
        int x = params[0].x;
        int y = params[0].y;
        int w = params[0].w;
        int h = params[0].h;
        GL10 gl = params[0].gl;

        SavePNG(0, 0, w,  h,  gl);
    }
```